# How to login using mediawiki's api, curl, and bash?

Tags: bash, curl, mediawiki

**My understanding of the process:**
From mediawikis login manual https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login

> When using MediaWiki's web service API, you will probably need your application or client to log in. This involves submitting a login query, constructing a cookie, and confirming the login by resubmitting the login request with the confirmation token returned.

1) Attempt to login with username and password, this will fail with 'result="NeedToken"' as part of response html. Response will also contain the token to be passed in for the next login attempt.
2) Attempt to login again, this time passing in token in addition to un/pw.  This should return with 'result="Success"'

**My code:**

```
###Attempt first login setup cookie jar
loginRes1=$(curl --cookie-jar cjar -X POST "$domain/wiki/api.php?action=login&lgname=$lgname&lgpassword=$lgpassword")

###Grab the token from login attempt
lgtoken=$(echo $loginRes1 |sed -rn "s/.*token=&quot;([0-9a-zA-Z]+)&quot;.*/\1/p" )

###Attempt second login, this time passing token as well
loginRes2=$(curl --cookie-jar cjar -X POST "$domain/wiki/api.php?action=login&lgname=$lgname&lgpassword=$lgpassword&lgtoken=$lgtoken")
```

**Result:**

```
echo $loginRes1
###Only relevant html from echo shown below, cleaned up into xml syntax
<?xml version="1.0"?> <api> <login result="NeedToken" token="944af711913a037cfb8b90d477d51f6c" cookieprefix="ronk" sessionid="isqvhm955lj35g1q2e2klme091" /> </api> 

echo $loginRes2 
###Only relevant html from echo shown below, cleaned up into xml syntax
<?xml version="1.0"?> <api> <login result="NeedToken" token="ffdd1aa6dc3699df26b9de6dd1c6d5a5" cookieprefix="ronk" sessionid="fdahoh4gh7junrqm1tk2p1qd25" /> </api>
```

I'm still getting the NeedToken result the second time, instead of Success as I would expect.

**Logging in via browser**
I can login normally with a browser with a form submission, the post request contains 4 parameters: wpName, wpPassword, wpLoginAttempt, wpLoginToken

```
wpName=myName&wpPassword=myPassword&wpLoginAttempt=Log+in&wpLoginToken=d3fe3a1de6fbc934acd3039149f3c56d
```

**Other Notes**
1) I confirmed that the un/pw works when logging in normally through a browser.
2) It's unclear to me if I'm using the curl cookie-jar syntax appropriately
3) I don't know the version of mediawiki I'm connecting to, it was installed recently and is likely the highest stable version.
4) You'll notice in the successful browser attempt, the parameters have the wp prefix instead of lg, if I change the curl attempt to match (i.e. wpName, wpPassword) then the returned result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <api> <warnings> <main xml:space="preserve">Unrecognized parameters: 'wpName', 'wpPassword'</main> </warnings> <login result="NoName" /> </api>
```

Comment: I think you are missing `-b cjar` to have curl load your cookies from the file.

Comment: @Etan Tried again with that change "curl -b cjar..." for loginRes2 , same result unfortunately

Comment: What does a successful login request from the browser look like?

Comment: @Etan updated question with "Logging in via browser" section

Comment: @Etan whoops originally I used the -b flag in addition to the --cookie-jar flag for the second login, instead of replacing it. Once I took out the --cookie-jar flag from the second attempt it worked.

Comment: Now it seems to work even with both flags there (which according to the curl help is what I would expect) I can only assume I had a typo previously

Comment: With `-b` everything is working?

Comment: @Etan yes, added Fix section at bottom showing the correction

Comment: Supplying your own answer (you can answer your own questions) is generally a better idea than editing the question to contain the answer. I just added the use of `-b` as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--cookie-jar` option to curl only tells curl to save cookies to the jar. It doesn't tell curl to **load** cookies from the jar.

To get curl to load cookies from the jar you need to use the `-b` option to specify the cookie jar to use.